# Fill input with array

Tags: php, wordpress-theming

In my jquery code I have:

```
$("#show").append("<img src=" +attachment.url+" alt="+attachment.alt+" title="+attachment.title+" description="+attachment.caption+" class='img-responsive img-thumbnail'/><input type='hidden'  name='my_image_URL[]' value="+attachment.url+"></span>");
```

My jquery code adds fields for news selected images and fills inputs names `my_image_URL[]`.

In PHP:

```
if ( isset( $_POST['my_image_URL'] ) ) {       
        $urls = $_POST['my_image_URL'];
         echo '<input type="hidden" name="imagens_home" value="'.$urls.'"/>';   
         }
```

I trying to add `$urls` array in the hidden input.

And after, if its works ok:

```
            <?php
                if ($urls != '' ) {

                foreach ($urls as $url) { 
             ?>                         
                    <img src="<?php echo $url;?>"  class="img-responsive img-thumbnail " />
                    <input name="my_image_URL[]" value="<?php echo $url;?>"/>
                </div>               
            <?php
                 };
                }
            ?>
```

But this part of code not fill the input:

```
if ( isset( $_POST['my_image_URL'] ) ) {       
        $urls = $_POST['my_image_URL'];
         echo '<input type="hidden" name="imagens_home" value="'.$urls.'"/>';   
         }
```

**----------  UPDATE  --------**

options.php

```
 register_setting(
            'tema-setting-group',//string $option_group
            'imagens_home' //string $option_name
            //calback $sanitize_calback      
        );

---
    add_settings_field(
         'home-imagens-top',//string $id
         'Imagens',//String $title
         'tema_home_imgs',//string $calback
         'opcoes_do_tema',//string $page    
         'tema-home-options'//string $section
         //string $args          
         );


//calback
function tema_home_imgs(){   
        $urlsImagens = esc_attr( get_option( 'imagens_home' ) ); // RETURN DB DATA

        include( get_template_directory() . '/inc/templates/selecao_imagens.php');

        if ( isset( $_POST['my_image_URL'] ) ) {

        $urls = $_POST['my_image_URL'];
             echo '<input name="imagens_home" value="'.$json_encode($urls).'" style="width:300px"/>';


        }   
    }
```

selecao_imagens.php

```
<input id="my_upl_button" type="button" value="Escolher Imagens" /><br/>

    <div class="row">
            <div id="exibe" class="sortable">       

            <?php           
            $urls = json_decode($urlsImagens, true);
                if ($urls != '' ) {
                foreach ($urls as $url) { 
             ?>          
                    <img src="<?php echo $url;?>"  class="img-responsive img-thumbnail " />
                    <input name="my_image_URL[]" value="<?php echo $url;?>"/>

            <?php
                 };
                }
            ?>
    </div>
    </div>
```

theme_options.php

```
 <?php settings_errors();?>

 <form method="post" action="options.php">
    <?php settings_fields ('tema-setting-group'); ?>

    <?php do_settings_sections (
    'opcoes_do_tema'//string $page

    ); ?>



    <?php submit_button (); 

    ?>  

 </form>
```

**--------  UPDATE 2  -------**

I tried:

```
echo '<input name="imagens_home" value="' . htmlspecialchars(json_encode($urls)) . '" />';
```

but it is not yet filling in the input.

I also tried only:

```
If (isset ($ _POST ['my_image_URL'])) {
 Print_r ($ _ POST ['my_image_URL']);

}
```

But after the submit does not appear anything on the screen, in the form correctly saves all other inputs except what I am trying to save the array, if I put some manual information goes ok. But I do not understand why it is not capturing the `my_image_URL []` names of each image input. The action in form is like this:

```
<Form method = “post” action = “options.php”>
```

I’m using the Settings API

Thanks

Comment: echo '<input type="hidden" name="imagens_home" value="'.$urls.'"/>';

it is hidden type so you sure that not working?

Comment: It does not really work I've removed the hidden temporarily

Comment: it `$urls` is a PHP array, you can't concatenate it to a string like that. You should convert it to a string that has a format corresponding to html values array attributes

Comment: Yes I tried using json_decode and json_enconde but I do not think I did it correctly

Answer (score 1):

> I trying to add $urls array in the hidden input.

If I understand, you're trying to store an array value in a hidden input, so you can retrieve it later. Problem is, this doesn't work...

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="imagens_home" value="'.$urls.'"/>';
```

...because when you echo  a PHP array all you get is the string `Array`, not the actual array contents.

You could turn the array into a json string though:

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="imagens_home" value="'.$json_encode($urls).'"/>';
```

Now your hidden input has a regular string. Later, when the form is POSTed, you could retrieve it:

```
$urls = json_decode($_POST['imagens_home'], true)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, but it's still not working for me, the input remains empty. The Alive to Die user solution also returns empty

Comment: @Gislef please be very specific. Which input remains empty? When? and how do you check?

Comment: @Gislef In `tema_home_imgs()` you are doing `json_encode($urls)` without ever assigning a value to `$urls` so json_encode is encoding nothing and you get a blank input. Before encoding, first set the variable: `$urls = $_POST['my_image_URL']`. Only then can you try to encode the `$urls` array

Comment: It was a typo in my question, I fixed the question. This way it is returning empty.